# libPNG reading RGBA at X,Y directly bypassing the buffer

Tags: c++, libpng

I am struggling to understand libPNG.

My intentions are to read data(BGRA) in my custom `for` loop 
I am short on memory - thus I don't want to read the whole image in to the `Buffer` I want to sample the PNG buffer directly form the PNG file.

Like `png_bgra ReadAt(Row, Column);` - is it possible to achieve that with libPNG ?

Comment: `libpng` has complete documentation of its API. When I had to be able to read a `png` image, I read through its documentation and was able to do the work I needed. I did not have your particular requirement, and I do not recall if `libpng` offers such incremental, on-the-fly extraction of raw image data. But, it's safe to say that if you can't find it in its documentation, it does not exist. So, you need to simply check libpng's documentation and figure it out yourself. Knowing where to find and how to read technical documentation is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well I did read it, but honestly I struggle to understand the language, as far as I see it kind of have many use cases and such, but I couldn't find the particular thing :(, I thought maybe I missed or misunderstood something and perhaps some1 already encountered it

Comment: `libpng` is also a C library with a C API, but it is capable of being used with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of the PNG format itself makes this impossible.

The contents of the IDAT chunk -- which contains the image data -- are compressed with zlib, which is a stream compressor. There is no way to decompress part of the image data without decompressing all of the data which leads up to it; additionally, decompressing that data will require a temporary buffer of up to 44 kB ([cf. "Memory Footprint"](https://www.zlib.net/zlib_tech.html)).

Comment: So we can't even decompress only lets say one row at a time ?

Comment: You can, but that's not what you asked. And, depending on the size of the image, the memory usage of the zlib temporary buffers (which persist across rows!) may negate the memory savings of not decompressing the whole image at once.